# Bitwise operations: online resources?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there a nice e-book (preferably PDF, like [Array and Pointers in C](http://home.earthlink.net/~momotuk/pointers.pdf)) explaining bitwise operations? Other resources also welcome, but I'm after a self-contained document, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't an ebook, but it's more of a "cookbook" of many applications of bitwise operations: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).